# Zend Framework: Fatal error on the server

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, url-rewriting

I'm trying to put a ZF website on the Internet which works well on my local machine (WAMP).

But on the Linux server, only the main page can be properly displayed. For the other pages, I've got a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception' with message 'Invalid
>   controller specified (error)' in
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:248
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) #1
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97):
>   Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #2
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Application.php(366):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() #3
>   /var/www/staging/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run() #4
>   {main} Next exception 'Zend_Controller_Exception' with message
>   'Invalid controller specified (error)#0
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
>   Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
>   Object(Zend_Contr in
>   /var/www/staging/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line
>   336.

I activated the URL rewriting. I'm using modules. The index.php and application.ini are very basic, we didn't custumize it.

I suppose that there is something wrong with the configuration... Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the result of `tree [path/to/src]` (the linux command) without the `library/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When deploying application from windows platform to Linux, most typical type of error that can be encountered is due to the filename cases.* Linux system are very strict about file name and cases.

The error you are encountering is also probably one of these cases. Check the name of `ErrorContainer.php` and try to match the name you specify in your route and file system.

Comment: Here are the details, to check my names/cases:

I can't display this page: `<server root>/FormApply`.

The controller is: `<server root>/application/modules/default/controllers/FormApplyController.php`.

The class is `Default_FormApplyController` and the method `indexAction`.

All that works on my local machine. Thanks.

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas, Match the case of directory as well

Comment: It finally works. I think my mistake was to create my names using camelCase, and I created a custom view helper too. So the mistake was in one of these files. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, is it possible to enforce the case sensitivity on Windows? So that I will see this problem sooner next time?

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas, This [might](http://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem) be some help.

Answer (score 0):

In changing server Windows => Linux. The first main things to check is ignore case in Windows. Check filenames and class names if spelled with proper first capital letter etc.